# Load a page plus changing the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've noticed that when `$this->load->view('page.php)'` is used, the URL in the browser does not change, ie. if we came from `../step_1.php` and loaded to `../step_2.php`, the url will still be `../step_1.php`.

I am making a multi-step form wherein all steps are handled by one controller and I've learned that the best way to handle such situations is using `load`. The problem is that I do not want the past page's URL to be shown but the new page's. I know `redirect('page_controller')` can achieve this but it would be unpractical (redirecting within the controller).

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

EDIT:

I found an explanation regarding CI's view and redirect from [this link](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewreply/662802/).

> views -> shows a page in the previous page's URL
>
> redirect -> shows a page in its own URL

Comment: what is ../step_1 is it a view or a controller?

Comment: ../step_1 is a view. Its controller is the one that also handles ../step_2 to ../step_n's

Comment: do you have a step_1 and step_2.php on your views directory?

Comment: Actually they are all in one subfolder inside the views directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
function step_1()
{
    load_page($step_1);
}
```

Instead of calling load_page from your view build your pages out in the controller as above, then call the appropriate page. CI uses the controller method as the URL. To my knowledge there is no way to change this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I've been doing exactly what you mentioned here. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class test{
{
    public function view()
    {

      switch($this->uri->segment(2))
      {
      case $this->uri->segment(2) == 'part1':
        $this->load->view('part1');
      break;
      case $this->uri->segment(2) == 'part2':
          $this->load->view('part2');
      break;
      }

    }
}
```

OR

```
class test{
{
    public function view($page)
    {

      switch($page)
      {
      case $page == 'part1':
        $this->load->view('part1');
      break;
      case $page == 'part2':
          $this->load->view('part2');
      break;
      }

    }
}




test/view/part1
will go to view part1
test/view/part2
will go to view part2
```

you could try something like this,
*this is not tested tell me if there are errors*

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry but I have a hard time understand the code. I have a function called `load_page($page_name)` and inside has `$this->load->view($page_name)`. Regarding the code, 'part1', 'part2' should be `$page_name` since I'm only passing the name of the view, which should be at the end of the uri segment. Am I right? :D

Comment: @thekalaban yup you are right, but it is up to you how you want to get the data out from the uri you could use segment uri, or method parameters its up to you